# The Below code is to find the count of highest number in a array. but it is not working

Tags: go

I am trying to get a highest number count using GO CODE below but i seems to be not working. which is a simple program but i was unable to get the correct answer which is 2 in this case.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print(findLargeNumberCount([]int32{4, 4, 1, 3}))
}

func findLargeNumberCount(candles []int32) int32 {
    var highest int32 = 0
    var prev int32 = candles[0]
    for i := 1; i < len(candles); i++ {
        if prev == candles[i] {
            highest++
        } else if candles[i] > prev {
            highest = 1
            
        }
        prev = candles[i]
    }
    return highest
}
```

Comment: Try first searching for the higher value, then, count how many times that item (the higher value) appears in your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code to have it works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print(findLargeNumberCount([]int32{4, 4, 1, 3}))
}

func findLargeNumberCount(candles []int32) int32 {
    var highest int32 = 1
    var prev int32 = candles[0]
    for i := 1; i < len(candles); i++ {
        if prev == candles[i] {
            highest++
        } else if candles[i] > prev {
            prev = candles[i]
            highest = 1

        }
    }
    return highest
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0OnUiGnfKXI

What was changed:

1. `var highest int32 = 1` , not 0
2. `prev = candles[i]` should be in else if block

Explanation:

Assume, that the first element of the slice(`candles` in code) is the highest one (`prev` in code) and set the count of the highest number to 1 (`highest` in code).

After that start iterating over the slice:

If we have an element of the slice (`candles[i]`  in code) that is equal to the current highest(`prev`) then we increase the highest number count (`highest`),

else if we have an element (`candles[i]`) that is higher than the current highest (`prev`) we assign new current highest `prev = candles[i]` and reset the highest number count to 1  `highest = 1` and keep iterating till the end of the slice.